# How does gateway connect other services in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, nestjs

I am attaching the image of my application flow. Here the Gateway and other services are created using NestJS. The request for any API comes through the gateway.

**The Gateway-pod and API-pod communicate using TCP protocol**.

**After deployment the Gateway is not able to discover any API pods.**

I am attaching the YAML image file also for both **Gateway & Pods**.
Please do let me know what mistake I am doing in the YAML file.

```
                    **APPLICATION DIAGRAM**
```

[image]

> Gateway YAML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: roushan
  name: gateway-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: roushan-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: roushan-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gateway-container
          image: nest-api-gateway:v8
          ports:
          - containerPort: 1000
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: roushan
  name: gateway-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: roushan-app
  ports:
    - name: gateway-svc-container
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 1000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

> Pod YAML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: roushan
  name: pod1-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: roushan-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: roushan-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pod1-container
          image: nest-api-pod1:v2
          ports:
          - containerPort: 4000
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   namespace: roushan
   name: pod1-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: roushan-app
  ports:
    - name: pod1-svc-container
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4000
```

Comment: Please paste your yaml files as formatted text, instead of pictures. It is now impossible to copy and paste your yaml to reproduce your problem. Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy your cluster?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I have provided the YAML code. Please look into it once. Thanks for your response.

Comment: the cluster is : Azure AKS with the version of : 1.21.7

Comment: Please also provide details how exactly did you create your whole infrastructure inside your cluster.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak, I just logged in to Azure portal and then selected AKS service and provided the details line cluster name, Network Police (Calico) etc. and then created the cluster with 3 Ubuntu-20.0.1  nodes.

Comment: Please answer the question provided by the Ross G in the comment below his answer ;)

Comment: Did the solution provided by Harsh Manvar help you?

Comment: @Mikolaj, thanks. The solution did not work for me.

Comment: Please run `kubectl describe` command on all your deployments and attach information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

the gateway should be able to access the services by their DNS name. for example pod1-srv.svc.cluster.local, if this does not work you may need to look at the Kubernetes DNS setup.

I have not used AKS, they may use a different domain name for the cluster other than svc.cluster.local

Comment: thanks for the response. I am getting the below error after changing the DNS. This error is my GATEWAY application log error. ClientTCP {
  routingMap: Map {},
  logger: Logger { context: 'ClientTCP', options: {} },
  isConnected: false,
  port: 80,
  host: '<Service Name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local'
}
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.0.102.122:80
  {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.0.102.122',
  port: 80
}  BASICALLY I AM GETTING CONNECTION REFUSED ERROR TO GATEWAY

Comment: And please note that with <Service Name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local this format it able to resolve the name, i.e. it is giving the CLUSTER IP corresponding to the Service. In the previous comment "10.0.102.122" is the IP address of this DNS.

Comment: looking at your pod1-srv.svc.cluster.local application code.  (I don't know which language you are using)  what ip address are you binding on (sometimes called listen address)?  make sure you don't  bind 127.0.0.1 otherwise the gateway wont be able to communicate with it as pod-1 would only be able to talk to itself.  i recommend 0.0.0.0 (which would be all ips without needing to know what IP kubernetes has assigned it).

Comment: I tried with 0.0.0.0 , but it did not work for me. And when I am using svc.cluster.local instead of 127.0.0.1 , then my pod itself is not running.

Comment: it wont work with dns names (because it is part of the IP stack way below dns), and 127.0.0.1 wont work as the  pod will only accept connections from itself.  you could try * instead of 0.0.0.0 but that setting is framework/application specific so without knowing what language/framework you are using it would be hard to assist further, though the framework/library docs should help.

Answer (score 0):

**YAML Points**

Ideally, you should be keeping the different **selectors** across the **deployment**.

You are using the same selectors for both deployments. Gateway and application deployment.

Service will forward the traffic to deployment based on selectors and labels, this might redirect the **service-2** request to **POD-1**.

**Networking**

You gateway service(Pods) connect to internal service by just `service-name` like : **pod1-srv** if in same namespaces.

if gateway and application in different namespaces you have to call each other like `http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: I thank you very much for your valuable comment. Actually, at very beginning the selector were different for different Deployments. As it was not working, I though let's keep the Selector as same for both Pod1 & Pod2 Deployment. But then also, it did not work.

Comment: if possible share YAML for reference so can get an idea.

Comment: As of now, I was thinking there may be the problem with TCP protocol, may be it need some special configuration on Cluster level to work with TCP instead of HTTP protocol. But now I have configured the cluster with RabbitMQ for the communication among pod. It is working absolutely fine. Hence proves, there is no problem with TCP protocol configuration. @Harsh, I am using exactly same YAML file what I provided in Question Section. Only, the original image name need to replace.